# in grouping getting duplicate records

Tags: sql-server

I want to filter records on the basis of month. Requirement is in month how much projects are in "completed, pending, started etc" status. This is my query but i am getting duplicate records.

```
SELECT distinct
        convert(varchar(7), w.ExpectedStartDate, 126) AS StatusOfMonth,
        COUNT(w.StatusTypeId) AS StatusCount,
        w.StatusTypeId,
        st.StatusTypeName

        FROM Table1 w
        LEFT OUTER JOIN StatusType st ON st.StatusTypeId = w.StatusTypeId
        WHERE   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), w.ExpectedStartDate, 103) BETWEEN '10/01/2011' AND '14/04/2011'
GROUP BY ExpectedStartDate, w.StatusTypeId, st.StatusTypeName
```

[image: Please see image to clarify what i want]

Please see image to clarify what i want. Please let me know how can i get correct results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your grouping by the date, not by the month or by the status of month
Group by

```
DATEPART(M, ExpectedStartDate)
```

or

```
convert(varchar(7), w.ExpectedStartDate, 126)
```

instead of just ExpectedStartDate

**EDIT**

In response the comment:
Try getting rid of

```
convert(varchar(7), w.ExpectedStartDate, 126) AS StatusOfMonth
```

and just try it like this:

```
SELECT
    convert(varchar, datepart(yyyy, w.ExpectedStartDate)) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)),
    w.StatusTypeId,
    st.StatusTypeName,
    COUNT(w.StatusTypeId) AS StatusCount
FROM 
    Table1 w LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    StatusType st ON st.StatusTypeId = w.StatusTypeId
WHERE   
    w.ExpectedStartDate BETWEEN '1/10/2011' AND '04/14/2011'
GROUP BY 
    datepart(M, w.ExpectedStartDate),
    datepart(yyyy, w.ExpectedStartDate),
    w.StatusTypeId,
    st.StatusTypeName
```

Comment: I have checked with <br />DATEPART(month, ExpectedStartDate) AS StatusOfMonth but it is showing same results. Give me other hint.

Comment: Hi @ Jeff,Thanks a lot this is working fine for me also. Great. Can i get date in format 2011-Dec (yyyy-MMM)?